# Change node colour when clicked on in d3 graph

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I would like to change the colour of a node when it is clicked on. I have some jquery to fetch and display some user information in a `<div>` on click:

```
 node.on("click", function(d) { 

    $.get("/user_info/" + d.name, function(data){

            $("#user").html(data);

        });
```

I'd like to be able to select the node and change its colour in the same code, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

I'm not sure if you want to do it once you click the node or when the request is over, so please take the following code and use what you need.

Note I'm using the .call method, which allows you to change the scope of the function (and to pass parameters to it).

The usage basically is

```
(function(){ console.log(this); console.log(arguments); }).call({ obj: "Hi, i'm the scope"},1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Run it in firebug to see what it does!

So, the function would look like:

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
    //In this context, 'this' is the element that got clicked
    $(this).css({ background: 'red' }); //Changes to red when clicked

    $.get("/user_info/" + d.name, (function(data){
            $(this).css({ background: 'blue' }); //Changes to blue when finished
            $("#user").html(data);

    }).call(this)); //'this' in this context refers to the node that was clicked, so we pass it as a scope for the anonymous function that will handle your request
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but the above code didn't work. I think this has to be done by using d3 to select and change the node attributes (e.g. not with a css hack)

Comment: My bad, I though the main issue were scopes, not the actual function to change the color :)